# Prove there exists measurable $B_k$ s.t. $\int f d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k \mu(B_k)$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be a (Borel?) measure on $\mathbb R$ and $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$ be $\mu$-measurable. An exercise asks me to prove that there exists measurable finite family $(B_k)_{k=1,\dots,n}$ such that

$$\int f d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k \mu(B_k).$$

This seems false to me. Let $\mu$ be the dirac measure at $0$, which is even a Borel measure. Let $f=x\cdot_{\{0\}}$ for some irrational $x$. Then the integral of $f$ is $x$ and clearly the sum on the right can never be irrational. Who is wrong: the exercise or me?

Comment: The exercise is wrong.